# SYNC and UPDATE at the same time between two tables in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having trouble on ORACLE SQL Operation. 
So first of all, I have two tables,

```
TEST_TABLE_A
Insert into TEST_TABLE_A (NAME, VAL1, VAL2, STATUS) Values ('HEAD1', 100, 200, 'ACTIVE');
Insert into TEST_TABLE_A (NAME, VAL1, VAL2, STATUS) Values ('HEAD2', 300, 400, 'ACTIVE');
Insert into TEST_TABLE_A (NAME, VAL1, VAL2, STATUS) Values ('HEAD3', 500, 600, 'ACTIVE');
Insert into TEST_TABLE_A (NAME, VAL1, VAL2, STATUS) Values ('HEAD4', 700, 800, 'ACTIVE');

TEST_TABLE_B
Insert into TEST_TABLE_B (NAME, VAL1, VAL2) Values ('HEAD1', 1, 2);
Insert into TEST_TABLE_B (NAME, VAL1, VAL2) Values ('HEAD4', 700, 800);
Insert into TEST_TABLE_B (NAME, VAL1, VAL2) Values ('HEAD5', 900, 1000);
```

My assignment is listed as follows,
1. Sync data from table b to table a
2. when the same name found with the same values then ignore
3. when the same name found with different values then insert the data into table A with the same name and the value grabbed from B and update the old row  with 'INACTIVE' status
4. when no data found in table A based on table B then insert the data into table A

my query is like this,

```
    MERGE INTO TEST_TABLE_A TGT
    USING TEST_TABLE_B SRC
        ON (TGT.NAME = SRC.NAME)

    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET TGT.VAL1 = SRC.VAL1,
               TGT.VAL2 = SRC.VAL2

    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (TGT.NAME, TGT.VAL1, TGT.VAL2, TGT.STATUS)
        VALUES (SRC.NAME, SRC.VAL1, SRC.VAL2, 'ACTIVE');
```

So I am facing the problem that i cant make #3 work. I tried many combination of SQL and its just doesnt happen to work.

And how do i make number 2 work by ignoring the same name with same values in both table?

I am hoping that the result would be like this

```
TEST_TABLE_A
NAME   VAL1   VAL2   STATUS
-----------------------------
HEAD1  100    200    INACTIVE
HEAD1  1      2      ACTIVE
HEAD2  300    400    INACTIVE
HEAD3  500    600    INACTIVE
HEAD4  700    800    ACTIVE
HEAD5  900    1000   ACTIVE
```

I really appreciate you guys help.
regards

Comment: Simply use `UNION` and `analytic`. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am hoping that the result would be like this

```
TEST_TABLE_A
NAME   VAL1   VAL2   STATUS
-----------------------------
HEAD1  100    200    INACTIVE
HEAD1  1      2      ACTIVE
HEAD2  300    400    INACTIVE
HEAD3  500    600    INACTIVE
HEAD4  700    800    ACTIVE
HEAD5  900    1000   ACTIVE
```

Ok, let's see how it could be done to satisfy each of the rules of your SQL.

1.The first thing is just a simple `UNION` of both tables.

2.Then, need to get rid of rows which are duplicate on `NAME`, `VAL1` and `VAL2` columns. So, use `ROW_NUMBER` analytic.

3.Finally, select the rows with `RANK` as 1.

```
SQL> SELECT name,
  2    val1,
  3    val2,
  4    status
  5  FROM
  6    (SELECT a.*,
  7      row_number() over(partition BY a.val1, a.val2 order by a.name, a.val1, a.val2) rn
  8    FROM
  9      ( SELECT name, val1, val2,'INACTIVE' status  FROM TEST_TABLE_A
 10      UNION
 11      SELECT b.*, 'ACTIVE' status FROM TEST_TABLE_B b ORDER BY 1
 12      ) A
 13    )
 14  WHERE rn = 1
 15  /

NAME                       VAL1       VAL2 STATUS
-------------------- ---------- ---------- --------
HEAD1                         1          2 ACTIVE
HEAD1                       100        200 INACTIVE
HEAD2                       300        400 INACTIVE
HEAD3                       500        600 INACTIVE
HEAD4                       700        800 ACTIVE
HEAD5                       900       1000 ACTIVE

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

So, that gives exactly the output you want.

*Update** Adding a test case on OP's request

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM test_table_a;

NAME                       VAL1       VAL2 STATUS
-------------------- ---------- ---------- --------------------
HEAD1                       100        200 ACTIVE
HEAD2                       300        400 ACTIVE
HEAD3                       500        600 ACTIVE
HEAD4                       700        800 ACTIVE

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE test_table_a_new AS
  2  SELECT name,
  3    val1,
  4    val2,
  5    status
  6  FROM
  7    (SELECT a.*,
  8      row_number() over(partition BY a.val1, a.val2 order by a.name, a.val1, a.val2) rn
  9    FROM
 10      ( SELECT name, val1, val2,'INACTIVE' status  FROM TEST_TABLE_A
 11      UNION
 12      SELECT b.*, 'ACTIVE' status FROM TEST_TABLE_B b ORDER BY 1
 13      ) A
 14    )
 15  WHERE rn = 1
 16  /

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> DROP TABLE test_table_a PURGE
  2  /

Table dropped.

SQL>
SQL> alter table test_table_a_new rename to test_table_a
  2  /

Table altered.

SQL> select * from test_table_a
  2  /

NAME                       VAL1       VAL2 STATUS
-------------------- ---------- ---------- --------
HEAD1                         1          2 ACTIVE
HEAD1                       100        200 INACTIVE
HEAD2                       300        400 INACTIVE
HEAD3                       500        600 INACTIVE
HEAD4                       700        800 ACTIVE
HEAD5                       900       1000 ACTIVE

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Lalit, your solution only shows the result. what i really need is to modify TEST_TABLE_A so that when i SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE_A the result would be as expected

Comment: Just drop `test_table_a` and create it as my select statement. Ok, see my edit.

Comment: Lalit, i think your update doesnt really work because i need to perform some insert and update on table A using values from table B. I cant just use select and fiters the result to display the desired result

Comment: So, what is the problem with my solution? It uses the values of table_b and modifies table_a. Did you understand the solution? I think `inset` and `update` is more of  work, you can use `CTAS` as I have demonstrated. It gives the required table_a with the data you want in it.

Comment: Just execute the steps and tell me where do you think it is wrong? Scroll the entire code part.

Comment: i tried that and execute it. after i execute it, then i select * from table a. then the the values from table a doesnt show any changes.

Comment: I have demonstrated a complete test case with the steps and the output. How does my test case shows `select * from test_table_a` correct values?

Comment: lalit your steps, for what i understand is getting the structure and move it to a new table by creating that table. What i have to do is modifying the contents in table A

Comment: **Yes, yes, yes. The table_a is finally modified.** What is there you don't understand. It is called `CTAS` approach, it means create table as select. It doesn't need any insert or update.

Comment: Lalit, my assignment is that I cant have 'dropping a table method'.

Comment: There are at least two "problems" with your solution: 1) it's better to use UNION ALL because the statuses are always different; 2) consider this case: table A {name=a, val1=1, val2=1}, table B {name=b, val1=1, val2=1} - your solution will ignore name=b

Comment: @Multisync, and why should I add data to test? It is OP's work to figure out if any modification is required. My solution is based on OP's inputs.

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

if HEAD2 and HEAD3 is INACTIVE

```
--> Update the data that does not exist in table BLE_B to be INACTIVE
 Update BLE_A
 Set STATUS = 'INACTIVE'
 From BLE_A a
 Left Join BLE_B b
    On b.Name = a.Name
    And b.Val1 = a.Val1
    And b.Val2 = a.Val2
 Where b.Name is Null


 --> Insert the data from BLE_B that does not exist in table BLE_A 
 --> or insert the data that different values with table BLE_A
 Insert Into BLE_A
 Select b.*, 'ACTIVE'
 From BLE_B b
 Left Join BLE_A a
    On a.Name = b.Name
    And a.Val1 = b.Val1
    And a.Val2 = b.Val2
 Where b.Name is Null
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use only one merge for #3 because you need to update and insert on the same ON condition.

```
update test_table_a a set a.status = 'INACTIVE' 
where exists (select 1 from test_table_b b 
               where b.name = a.name and (b.val1 != a.val1 or b.val2 != a.val2));

merge into test_table_a a using test_table_b b on (b.val1 = a.val1 and b.val2 = a.val2)
when not matched then insert values (b.name, b.val1, b.val2, 'ACTIVE');
```

But I don't understand why in your output HEAD2 and HEAD3 are in 'INACTIVE' status. Maybe you also need to mark as 'INACTIVE' the rows in TEST_TABLE_A which don't exist in TEST_TABLE_B (in this case you may change the first update by adding this condition: "OR not exists (select 1 from test_table_b b where b.name = a.name)")

Comment: HEAD2 and HEAD3 are set INACTIVE because it doesnt exists in TABLE B. The program flow is to sync values from table b to table A. if it doesnt exists in table b, that means the name is deleted that means it sets inactive

Comment: i did try like this but doesnt work, `update test_table_a a set a.status = 'INACTIVE' 
where exists (select 1 from test_table_b b 
               where b.name = a.name and (b.val1 != a.val1 or b.val2 != a.val2))
OR not exists (select 1 from test_table_b b where b.name = a.name);

merge into test_table_a a using test_table_b b on (b.val1 = a.val1 and b.val2 = a.val2)
when not matched then insert values (b.name, b.val1, b.val2, 'ACTIVE');`

Comment: @Chris Weltes, I don't understand how this solution is the answer to your question as you have marked it answered. Either you did not understand the solution, or you don't know what you want.

Comment: @LalitKumarB this solution from multisync updates the TEST_TABLE_A Itself and thats my desired result

Comment: Prove it. **SHOW** the use case.

Comment: I get what you mean now lalit kumar and it works best. But i am considering this case. When we finihed sync TABLE A and We want to sync the already synced table A with table C lets say. how do i process this so that the items that only sync with table is C is only the item that has 'ACTIVE' status

Comment: I don't get it :) What's wrong with my solution? Have you added "OR not exits" as I wrote? The first update marks as 'INACTIVE' the rows with the names which don't exist in table B or the rows with the names which exist in table B but have another values. The second merge just insert the new or changed rows. Of cause it can be done with the select more effectively, but it wasn't the case at the beginning.